# Magic methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I recently became aware that instead of using

```
$users = User::all();
return view('home')->with('users', $users);
```

You are able to do

```
return view('home')->withUsers($users);
```

I believe these are known as 'magic methods' - are these documented somewhere? Is there a list I can find or is that the only one?

Comment: The docs?  What you're asking is pretty broad, as laravel uses this everywhere including your `User::all()` call.  PHP calls them magic methods http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php, some languages just call it overloading.  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper is a package that will create PHPDoc entries for some of the "magic" in Laravel.

Comment: `The docs?` - link me the docs for this then?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views.  It looks like they've removed it in recent versions of docs, probably to discourage reliance on the magic methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel allows you to to pass data in that way out of convenience, but they aren't *magic methods*. [Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) is the name given to a select set of methods in PHP classes, that usually start with a double underscore `__`, each with their own purposes. Examples of magic methods are [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), [`__callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic), [`__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) etc.

Laravel uses PHP's magic methods, in particular the `__call` magic method, to provide the functionality that you're experiencing. The [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method is called by PHP when you try to call a method that does not exist on an object. As its first parameter it receives the name of the method that was called and the second parameter it receives the arguments that were passed to the method call as an array.

Laravel leverages this by implementing the `__call` method on the `View` class. It checks to see if the beginning of the method that the developer called starts with `with` and if so, it will assume that the following part of the method name represents the name of the variable that you want to bind data to when rendering your view:

**From `Illuminate\View\View`:**

```
/**
 * Dynamically bind parameters to the view.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 *
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (! Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
        throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on view.");
    }

    return $this->with(Str::camel(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
}
```

This provides the functionality that you're experiencing and this technique is in fact used in a few different places, for example, in the Query builder/Eloquent you can dynamically add where clauses to a query using by simply calling a method beginning with `where` and the remainder of the method call refers to the column you're checking:

```
User::whereEmail('foo@bar.com'); // Equal to User::where('email', 'foo@bar.com');
```

Comment: So would I have to look in Illuminate\whatever to see whether it supports this functionality or is there a predefined list somewhere? I couldn't see one with a quick search.

Comment: I'm not sure of a specific list that describes the types of places where this is used. In fact I think the documentation on it is pretty sparse anyway. Off the top of my head you can use it with Eloquent, the query builder, mailables, responses and views. There are likely more. Generally speaking whenever there's a `->with(...)` method or a method you can pass in a mapping of a string to a variable, that functionality is likely to exist.