# How to insert SQL column name to Raw Query from PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this code in Laravel:

```
DB::table('items')
    ->whereRaw("? = 1", ['active'])
    ->get();
```

In my database table, I have a column named `active` and the query I want to run is:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE active=1
```

My code fails because the query passes my `'active'` parameter as a String instead of a column name in SQL syntax (which is the expected behavior).
So, instead of the above, I get something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE "active"=1
```

Any idea how to solve this?

PS: I tried the MySQL function TRIM but with no success (perhaps I did not do it correctly).

Comment: Why not use `DB::table('items')->where('active',1)`?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic. In reality, `active` is `monday`. I have all the days in my db with value either 1 or 0. So, I want to be able to say "If today is Monday and `monday` is 1 in my table, select this item". My way, I will be able to use for example Carbon and get the name of the day today and dynamically pass this into my query.

Comment: Why not use `DB::table('items')->where($day,1)` ?

Comment: @ArthurSamarcos yes, this would work if I chained the `whereRaw` method with a `where` method (since I have more SQL code in the `whereRaw`) but I was wondering if I can do it in the `whereRaw`

Answer (score 1):

It is not the cleanest way;

```
$day = 'Monday'; // dynamically Tuesday, Wednesday....
$method = 'where' . $day;

return DB::table('items')->$method('1')->get();
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the answer. This works (even though I was really wondering how to do it in the whereRaw method because I have more SQL code there - but I can chain the methods if necessary). Can you explain why this works? Does the `$method` get substituted with `whereMonday` for example? And why does this work?

Comment: @padawanTony  Yes, you it substitutes it with magic method and allow you to chain it. this post explains it https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918904/2188922 very well.